# Rails 3 - how to save (un)checked checkboxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model, checkbox, update-attributes

I have in a form (**form_tag**) several checkboxes like this:

```
<%=check_box_tag 'model_name[column_name]', 1, (@data.model_name.column_name == 1 ? true : false)%>
```

And updating them like:

```
variable = ModelName.find(params[:id])             
variable.update_attributes(params[:model_name])
```

This works only in a moment, when I check some checkboxes - send them and they will be saved. That's fine.
But when I uncheck all checkboxes - send form - so nothing happend, in the DB table will not set the value **0** in the columns...

Could you give me any tip, how to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This happens because an unchecked checkbox will not send any value to the server. To circumvent this Rails provides the [`check_box`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) helper, which generates code like this:

```
<input type="hidden"   name="model[attr]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="model[attr]" value="1" />
```

Alternatively, insert a hidden field with `hidden_field_tag`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'model_name[column_name]', '0' %>
<%= check_box_tag 'model_name[column_name]', 1, (@data.model_name.column_name == 1 ? true : false) %>
```

Comment: thanks, but the hidden input must be before the checkbox, in the sequence as you writing it doesn't works me

Comment: This method works, but for me I have `<%= hidden_field_tag 'model_name[column_name]' %>` and it stores an empty set of quotes at the beginning of the array... How do I get rid of the extra empty quotes?