# update_attribute using where clause in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my communication table I have some columns:

```
id | UserID | CommunicationMode | CommunicationDetail | Private
1  | 1      | Phone             | 123456789           | 1
2  | 1      | Email             | abc@abc.com         | 1
```

And I want to update column value using where clause using loop like below:

```
create
    @user_communication=Communication.where(:UserID => current_user.id)
    if !@user_communication.blank?
      @user_communication.each do |c|
        if params[:ChkBx_Phone].to_i == 1
          c.where("CommunicationMode == 'Phone'").update_attribute( :Private, "1")
        elsif params[:ChkBx_Phone].to_i == 0
          c.where("CommunicationMode == 'Phone'").update_attribute( :Private, "0")
        end
        if params[:ChkBx_Email].to_i == 1
          c.where("CommuicationMode == 'Email'").update_attribute( :Private, "1")
        elsif params[:ChkBx_Email].to_i == 0
          c.where("CommunicationMode == 'Email'").update_attribute( :Private, "0")
        end
      end  
    end
end
```

I want to check above that if `Phone` checkbox is checked then it updates `Private` column with value `1` else `0` where `CommunicationMode is Phone`  and for email I want to check that if `Email` checkbox is checked then it updates `Private` column with value `1` else `0` where `CommunicationMode is Email`

And below is `Phone` and `Email` checkboxes:

```
    <table>
    <% @user_communication.each do |c| %>
           <tr>
               <td>
                  <% if c.CommunicationMode == "Phone" and c.Private.to_s == "1" %>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="ChkBx_Phone"
                        id="ChkBx_Phone" value="1" checked = "checked">
                            <%= label(:lb_Phone, "Phone") %>
                  <% elsif c.CommunicationMode == "Phone" and c.Private.to_s == "0" %>
                                <%= check_box_tag 'ChkBx_Phone' %>
                                <%= label(:lb_Phone, "Phone") %>
                  <% end %>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <% if c.CommunicationMode == "Email" and c.Private.to_s == "1" %>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ChkBx_Email"
                        id="ChkBx_Email" value="1" checked = "checked">
                        <%= label(:lb_Email, "Email") %>
                   <% elsif c.CommunicationMode == "Email" and c.Private.to_s == "0" %>
                        <%= check_box_tag 'ChkBx_Email' %>
                        <%= label(:lb_Email, "Email") %>                    
                   <% end %>
              </td>
           </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

But I am getting an error below:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Communication:0x4bc5490>
```

But when I am using below code:

```
create
    @user_communication=Communication.where(:UserID => current_user.id)
    if !@user_communication.blank?
      @user_communication.each do |c|
        if params[:ChkBx_Phone].to_i == 1
          puts "Hassan2"
          c.update_attribute( :Private, "1")
        elsif params[:ChkBx_Phone].to_i == 0
          puts "Ali2"
          c.update_attribute( :Private, "0")
        end
      end  
    end
end
```

Its working fine but it update both `Private column` value of `Phone` and `Email` and I have checked only `Phone` checkbox.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kingston said, when you iterate through the `@user_communication` collection, the `c` variable in the block is in fact a concrete `Communication` object, not an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object, which is what contains the `.where` query methods.

Additionally, there are a couple of other problems I have noticed. Some, I cannot directly help you solve because I don't know how your system works, but I will point them out for you and try to suggest an alternative, and hopefully you can figure out the best way to fix them in the context of your system's requirement.

In regards to the `create` method, there are two approaches that will have the same end result, but one of them I would consider the "naïve approach". I'm going to show the naïve approach only to give you a direct alternative/answer to the first create method you posted, and so you can see the difference and figure out the best solution:

**Naïve Approach**:

```
def create
  @user_communication=Communication.where(:UserID => current_user.id)

  # Transaction so we don't execute X number of individual update statements
  Communication.transaction do 

    @user_communication.each do |c|

      if c.CommunicationMode == "Phone"
        # Note: Its not necessary to use the ternary operator if you're not 
        # comfortable with it, however it can save you a few lines of code.
        c.update(Private: (params[:ChkBx_Phone].to_i == 1 ? "1" : "0") )
      elsif c.CommunicationMode == "Email"
        c.update(Private: (params[:ChkBx_Email].to_i == 1 ? "1" : "0") )
      end

    end # end communication loop

  end # end transaction
end
```

This will iterate through the the `Communication` objects for that user id, and update each one based on its `CommunicationMode` value, setting it to a 1 or a 0, depending on the value of the two checkboxes. What you will see in your log are several individual `UPDATE` statements for each `Communication` object you have in the collection. Normally, the database will execute the `UPDATE` statement immediately, since the updates are wrapped in their own transactions, and consequently, this becomes rather costly over time if you have a large number of records. So to avoid that problem, as you can see I've wrapped the entire operation in a transaction, and consequently, the updates are only committed at the end; this is much more efficient (you can do some experiments to verify this yourself; you should be able to see a noticeable time difference with and without the transaction wrapper).

And now, the "potentially" better approach:

**The "Potentially" better / less naïve approach**

```
... other method code
Communication.where(UserID: current_user.id, CommunicationMode: "Phone").update_all(Private: (params[:ChkBx_Phone].to_i == 1 ? "1" : "0") )

Communication.where(UserID: current_user.id, CommunicationMode: "Email").update_all(Private: (params[:ChkBx_Email].to_i == 1 ? "1" : "0") )
```

This will execute only two `UPDATE` statements (which you can also wrap in a transaction if you like). This should execute even quicker than the above approach, and saves you even more lines of code.

Note that both this and the naïve approach can be moved to a method in the `Communication` model, to keep heavy model-related operations out of the controller.

**Another issue of note**

In your view code, you appear to be iteration over a collection `@user_communication`, within which you're creating a checkbox for each object:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ChkBx_Email" id="ChkBx_Email" value="1" checked = "checked">
```

Consequently, if you have five objects in that collection, you'll see a list of five checkboxes. Because of the way you've named this input, only one of the values is ever being sent (I believe it is typically the "last" input in the DOM). In other words, if you click "on" the first checkbox, but leave the last one "off", the value of the checkbox will be "off". I have a strong feeling this is probably not how you want your system to behave. Perhaps you will want to place those checkboxes outside of the loop (above), since they don't appear to have anything to do with the `Communication` objects themselves.

Additionally, an unchecked checkbox is never sent to the server. The line `params[:ChkBx_Phone].to_i == 1` will crash if you unchecked that checkbox because `params[:ChkBx_Phone]` is nil, and you'd be invoking `to_i` on a nil object. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9405273/877472) shows you an alternative for this solution. In your case, you will want to make sure of the Rails helper tags, such as [`check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag), and [`hidden_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag), like so:

```
<%=hidden_field_tag 'ChkBx_Phone', '0'%>
<%=check_box_tag 'ChkBx_Phone', '1', true %>
```

As a result, if the checkbox is unchecked, because of the existence of the identically named hidden field input, the server will always receive a value for this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
 @user_communication.each do |c|    
 # Your logic
 end
```

you looping `@user_communication` then `c` variable will contain `Communication object` not `Active record relation`,then you are doing `c.where()`,c contain `Communication object`. But **.where** `Active record relation`.so it is throwing error.